# DataTables.js: how to loop thru rows in a table with pagination, accessing cell's custom data-attributes and setting custom html inside

Tags: jquery, pagination, custom-data-attribute, datatables-1.10

My table (for simplicity with 1 row):

```
<table id="js_objects_functional_table" class="functional_table">
    <thead>
        <th>Object Name<span class="smallquestionsign" style="top: 3px" rel="tooltip" title="Header text"></span></th>
        <th>Source<span class="smallquestionsign" style="top: 3px" rel="tooltip" title="Header text"></span></th>
        <th>Status<span class="smallquestionsign" style="top: 3px" rel="tooltip" title="Header text"></span></th>
        <th>Progress<span class="smallquestionsign" style="top: 3px" rel="tooltip" title="Header text"></span></th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="js_objects_functional_table_tbody">
        <tr class="js_table_object_row" data-object-id="objectId1">

            <td data-filter="Object Name" data-sort="Object Name" data-order="Object Name" data-search="Object Name"><span data-object-id="objectId1" class="js_goto_object_page paragraph_textstyle__link">Object Name<span class="smallquestionsign" style="top: 3px" rel="tooltip" title="Object definition"></span></span></td>

            <td data-filter="Custom" data-sort="Custom" data-order="Custom" data-search="Custom"><span data-object-id="objectId1" class="object_custom_source">Custom</span></td>

            <td data-filter="calculating" data-sort="calculating" data-order="calculating" data-search="calculating" class="js_table_object_status" data-object-id="objectId1">Calculating...</td>

            <td data-sort="-1" data-order="-1" class="js_table_object_progress" data-object-id="objectId1">Calculating...</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

My js (that works for table without pagination):

```
//Part 1:

var ajaxObject = {objects: []}; // ajaxObject.objects - array of data-object-ids of cells with class="js_table_object_status" that have text "Calculating..." inside
$("#js_objects_functional_table").children("tbody").children("tr").children(".js_table_object_status").each(function(){  //Looping thru cells with class="js_table_object_status"
    var textInside = $(this).text()
    if (textInside.indexOf("Calculating") >= 0){
        var objectId = $(this).attr("data-object-id")
        var teamId = "none"
        var element = {};
        element.objectId = objectId
        element.teamId = teamId
        ajaxObject.objects.push(element);
    }
})

//Part 2. As result of AJAX call for 1 cell with class="js_table_object_status" :

var objectId = result.objectId;
var objectStatus = result.objectStatus;
var className = result.className;

var element = $("#js_objects_functional_table").children("tbody").children("tr").children(".js_table_object_status[data-object-id='" + objectId + "']") //Finding cell with data-object-id = given objectId and with class="js_table_object_status" 
element.empty()
element.attr("data-filter", objectStatus).attr("data-sort", objectStatus).attr("data-order", objectStatus).attr("data-search", objectStatus) //Assigning new datatTable data-attributes' values

element.append('<span class="'+className+'">'+ objectStatus +'</span>')
```

My question: how to fix my code so I could do the same things with a table with pagination (accessing information that is "behind" the pagination)

I tried this for part 1 and got stuck. I don't know how to access the custom data-attribute data-object-id.:

```
$("#js_objects_functional_table").DataTable().cells('.js_table_object_status').every(function(){ 
    var data = this.data();
    console.log(data)
    var textInside = data
    if (textInside.indexOf("Calculating") >= 0){
        var objectId = this.attr("data-object-id") 
        var teamId = "none"
        var element = {};
        element.objectId = objectId
        element.teamId = teamId
        ajaxObject.objects.push(element);
    }
})
```

For the second part i don't know even more: how to empty the cell from inner html, how to change DataTables data-attributes' values and how to insert inner html inside.

Would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`rows.every()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().every()) to iterate through all the rows, use to$() to work on the rows as jQuery instances :

```
table.rows().every(function() {
  var cells = this.nodes().to$().children('.js_table_object_status');
  cells.each(function() {
    if (~$(this).text().indexOf("Calculating")) {
      var objectId = $(this).attr("data-object-id")
      var teamId = "none"
      var element = {};
      element.objectId = objectId
      element.teamId = teamId
      ajaxObject.objects.push(element);
    }
  })
})
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/qq09bp6m/**

It is not clear how and then you want to update the table. If you want it to do it in the loop, you can work directly on the elements and update using `invalidate()` :

```
table.rows().every(function() {
  var row = this;
  var cells = row.nodes().to$().children('.js_table_object_status');
  cells.each(function() {
    var e = $(this); 
    if (~e.text().indexOf("Calculating")) {
      var objectId = e.attr("data-object-id")
      var teamId = "none"
      var element = {};
      element.objectId = objectId
      element.teamId = teamId
      ajaxObject.objects.push(element);

      e.html('<span>test</span>');
      e.attr('data-sort', 'someValue');
      row.invalidate().draw();
    }
  })
})
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/qq09bp6m/1/**

Or elsewhere a table wide search can be done with [`table.$()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/%24()) :

```
table.$('.js_table_object_status[data-object-id="objectId1"]')
  .attr('data-sort', 27)
  .addClass('someClass')
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/qq09bp6m/2/**